# What are the new 3D cursor features introduced in 2.73?

Tags: modeling, 3d-cursor

Just noticed that while dragging the 3D cursor values for constrained axis can be entered, and the cursor can snap to faces. The status header shows MEDIAN,Global,FACE how can these properties be influenced?

[image]

Comment: Check : http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73

Comment: I think you would probably find a good answer if you checked the release notes.

Comment: @iKlsR I installed 2.73 and didn't expect that it keeps the add-ons. Therefore I couldn't find anything in the release notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is added by the [Enhanced 3D cursor addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Enhanced_3D_Cursor) it is best to read it's rather long usage entry to learn about it's functionality.

[image]